# Are compilers smart enough to optimize functors with members the same as static method arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, portability, compiler-optimization

I'm interested in writing performant code across several compilers (GCC, MSVC, Clang). I've seen two patterns for passing functions as compile time arguments, and I'm curious if compilers are usually smart enough to recognize the two are equivalent, or if I'm asking too much. Here's the STL style, passing a functor object:

```
  template<class InputIterator, class Predicate>
  InputIterator find_if ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred )
  {
    for ( ; first!=last ; first++ ) if ( pred(*first) ) break;
    return first;
  }
```

And here's the alternative style:

```
  template<class InputIterator, class Predicate, class PredData>
  InputIterator find_if ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, PredData data )
  {
    for ( ; first!=last ; first++ ) if ( Predicate::eval(*first, data) ) break;
    return first;
  }
```

In the STL style, your Predicate class typically contains as members any data it needs, and you call operator() to evaluate the predicate. In the alternative style, you never have a Predicate object, rather it contains a static method that takes the item to be checked, and the data is passed as an argument rather than stored as a member on Predicate.

I have a few fears using the STL style:

1. If Predicate is a word or smaller, will the compiler be smart enough to pass it by register? In the alternative style the word would be an argument, so the compiler doesn't have to infer anything.
2. If Predicate is empty, will it be smart enough to avoid instantiating and passing it? In the alternative style Predicate is never instantiated.

So my intuition is the alternative style should be faster, but perhaps I'm underestimating modern optimizers.

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience with gcc (g++) modern compilers are absolutely capable of optimizing functors. The one case where this might not be true is when a functor is in a different compilation unit.

That said this should not deter you, the C++ library and direction rewards you by using the modern style, it is a much more manageable language using the abstractions.

I ran a experiment comparing a for loop using for, std::for_each (with function), std::for_each (with functor) and std::for_each (with lambda). The compiler was able to see past that inlined them all and each has the same execution time and number of instructions (although the structure of the instructions where slightly different).

Finally, Herb Sutter said in one of his presentations (at build i think) that C++ style over C style add only 3% overhead, which is nothing in comparison to its greater security.

Comment: C++ style can add no overhead, but can also make code hell of a lot slower. Or writing in C can slow down by twice compared to C++ if you don't know what you are doing. I.e. hummer is a good tool but in wrong hands it can do a lot of harm. It is totally unclear what the hell Herb was measuring and how. Compilers are, of course, capable, but it never hurts to verify what they generate if you talk about high-performance code.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko I couldn't agree more, C++ can and often is faster (take the standard quick sort). However when talking with board strokes, assuming both C and C++ are programmed well on the whole C++ is slightly slow. But the benefit for me far out weigh the 3% or whatever.

Comment: For your experiment did you try with and without members?

Comment: @Joseph Garvin: to be fair they had no member because it had to be a fair test against the normal C function. When members where included then it is offering utilities above and beyond what can be achieved with normal functions. That said I have used lambdas and functor all over the place and have noticed a slow down when they have had members. I really wouldn't worry about performance in these situations.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can performa a number of optimizations, but one thing to keep in mind is that different compilers will have different optimizations and what works best on one might not have an affect on another.

In C++11 there are move semantics that can optimize the copy of the Predicate object. Since this is in the standard, all compilers should implement this same optimization, and the first style would have close performance as the second one.

Another point in favor of the STL style is that being a common pattern, you probably have more chances of compiler optimizations, as compiler vendors will be targeting those usage patterns.

Also, you should evaluate the performance gains with a profiler, since programmers are usually bad at guessing what and where bottlenecks in code are.